# Poincaré-Hopf Index Theorem - Intuitive explanation

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, vector-analysis

I heard about an interesting theorem.

> Poincaré-Hopf Index Theorem : If $\vec{v}$ is a smooth vector filed on
>   the compact, oriented manifold $X$ with only finitely many zeros, then
>   the global sum of the indices of $\vec{v}$ equals the Euler
>   characteristics on $X$.

Does someone could take the time to explain this theorem intuitively?

Comment: Have you read any textbook treatments of the Poincare-Hopf treatment? I like the book by Guilleman and Pollack.

Comment: Yes, this comment come from this book. Before beginning, I would have liked to describe me the intuitive nature of this theorem (with a drawing, a sketch if possible).

Comment: @RobertDavis Roughly, one way to motivate this intuitively is the following: You look at the diagonal inside $X \times X$. Let it flow according to the one parameter diffeomorphism defined by the vector field. Then take the intersection number with the diagonal (=euler characteristic).